# Three.js click event using Raycaster and OrthographicCamera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I feel like this question has been asked a million times so I apologize but I cannot get any of the solutions to help in my situation.

I have a simple mouse event here:

```
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("click", onclick, false);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onclick(event) {
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth  ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

  console.log('intersects', intersects);
}
```

My project consists of a 2 column layout with three.js being in the right column. This is why I am using `renderer.domElement.clientHeightHeight` (at least I think this is what I should be using).

Secondly, I am using `scene.children` since I am adding all of  my meshes to the sceen like so:

```
scene.add( door );
scene.add( leftWall );
scene.add( rightWall );
scene.add( topWall );
scene.add( bottomWall );
scene.add( baseGridFloor );

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Anyways, when I click in my scene, I am getting this logged to the console

`intersects: []`

If I had to guess what is wrong here is that the raycast is not casting in the correct place so it is not returning any intersection objects. Just guessing here though.

Comment: `clientHeightHeight`? Seems like a typo. It should be just `clientHeight`.

Comment: Oh, I was so hoping it was that. Im sure that was not helping but after correcting it still results in the same outcome: https://d.pr/free/i/BOBNer

Comment: Can you please try to demonstrate the issue with a live example? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/